# Changing background color of SegementedPickerStyle (UIKit & SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol, swiftui-picker

I'm using a Picker view in SwiftUI to navigate between 1 of 3 pages. However, I'm having difficulties figuring out how to customize the SegmentedPickerStyle.

The vision I have for the picker is very simple... It would look like:

```
Feed | For You | Tools
```

Thing is, instead of looking like buttons (as the SegmentedPickerStyle does by default) it'd simply be text, using an underline to represent the *selectedSegment* [Here's a mockup of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FRf5.gif)

So far I've been able to only figured out how to customize:

1. The entire Picker's font color
2. The *SelectedSegment*'s background
   color
3. The entire Picker's background color, **however**, it doesn't work with UIColor.clear or UIColor.White for some reason?

The only way I've been able to customize the picker is by overriding the UIKit component which SwiftUI inherits from, *UISegmentedControl*.

Here my code:

```
import SwiftUI

enum HomeTab: String, CaseIterable {
    case Feed = "Feed"
    case ForYou = "For You"
    case Tools = "Tools"
}

struct SelectedHomeTab: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: HomeTab
    
    var body: some View {
        switch selectedTab {
        case .Feed:
            Text("Feed!")
        case .ForYou:
            Text("For you!")
        case .Tools:
            Text("Tools!")
        }
    }
}


    struct HomeView: View {
        @State private var currentTab: HomeTab = .ForYou
        
        // Change SegementedPicker styling
        init() {
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(named: "navyBlue") // custom asset color (what i want the underline to be)
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .selected)
            UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Picker("", selection: $currentTab) {
                    ForEach(HomeTab.allCases, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                
                SelectedHomeTab(selectedTab: self.$currentTab)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    struct HomeTab_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
```

Banging my head against the wall for a few hours now... any help is greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Since it looks so different than the original `Picker` (and SwiftUI is pretty easy to build controls with), I'd probably opt for making a custom control rather than fiddling with `UIAppearance`.

Comment: @jnpdx Jheeze, really? I've been trying to avoid that route, kinda gives me a headache thinking about having to go back & write a picker from scratch. I guess there really isn't **always** an elegant solution when using new tech. If only UIKit was fully supported via SwiftUI modifiers... /rant. Thanks for your response

Comment: @gldmendonca If you feel like you could sufficiently modify `UISegmentedControl`, there's no reason you couldn't wrap it in `UIViewRepresentable`. If you decide to build from scratch, certainly the ugliest thing would be the touch animation (this looks like an Android, control, right)? If you get stuck on the line animation, look into `PreferenceKey`s